# Angular minification with grunt results in 'Failed to instantiate module' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am aware of setting up a controller, service, model etc for prepping for minification. I have about 20 controllers, models and services as individual files and I want to minify and concat them all into one JS file for production.

To get an idea of how I have these files setup, here is an example:

```
VforumJS.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$location', '$sce', 'MainModel', 'LogModel', 'MainDebug', 'timecode', 'Idle', function($scope, $location, $sce, MainModel, LogModel, MainDebug, timecode, Idle)
{
  ...
}]);
```

After minification, I get the error

```
Failed to instantiate module VforumJS due to:
  Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=a
```

If I click the error link, it says `Unknown provider: a`

Here is where my module gets created

```
var VforumJsConfig = function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, localStorageServiceProvider)
{
  localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('vforumdesktop');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    ...
  })
  .otherwise({
    ...
  });
};

var VforumJS = angular.module('VforumJS', ['ngRoute','LocalStorageModule', 'ngTouch', 'ui-rangeSlider','base64','ngIdle'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'localStorageServiceProvider', VforumJsConfig])
.constant('LogTypes', {
  LOGIN:          1,
  IDLE_LOGOUT:    2,
  MANUAL_LOGOUT:  3,
  VFORUM_OPEN:    4,
  VFORUM_CLOSE:   5
})
.constant('SendLogs', false)
.constant('MainDebug', true);
```

Am I maybe not doing the proper minification prep in the above code where the module is created?

Here is my `Gruntfile.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt)
{
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      all_src: {
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapName: 'source.map'
        },
        src: 'resources/js/**/*.js',
        dest: 'composite.all.min.js'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

Comment: Doesn't .config(VforumJsConfig) need to be using the minification contructor form? .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'localStorageServiceProvider', VforumJsConfig])

Comment: Take a look at ngAnnotate https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate it might help you.

Comment: @shieldstroy I just tried that and still the same error. @yvesmancera, I tried using ng-annotate yesterday but could not get the dang thing to run. I think maybe I was using the wrong syntax, but I couldn't figure out how to run `ng-annotate OPTIONS 'my/file/name.js'`

Comment: Based on the code you've given us, the `.config()` call *has* to be the culprit, as @shieldstroy has brought up. If that's not working, post the portion of your minified file that instantiates the module.

Comment: Not sure what `config()` you saw, but I edited it to injected the providers I am using

Comment: Try to isolate the injection that cause the unknown provider. If you have a "resolve" in your routeProvider config (you didn't show us the code), make sure to use the array aswell to inject arguments into functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your .config is definitely one of the issues. Double check and make sure that everywhere in your code that you are injecting a service/provider that you are using the in-line minification.

This is what a config injecting one provider (just $logProvider for this example) will look like after minification:

```
.config(function(a){
  console.log("Never gets here, but a is", a);
})
```

When really it should look like this:

```
.config(['$logProvider', function(a){
  console.log("a is", a);
}])
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/troylelandshields/pen/xGjKGV

Comment: so is my updated config line still not correct? Is `$logProvider` something I need to include? Could minifying already minified files cause issues? I forgot I have some plugins that are already minified, however, my grunt is minifying them anyway

Comment: I double checked all my files and I am certainly using inline minification

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear, I was using $logProvider as a general example. If you made it look like that with the providers that you are using then that is fine.

Comment: Is it possible that you missed adding the string into the array for just a single parameter in one of your controllers or services?

Comment: gotcha, ok. I thought so and had removed it and just did that for the providers I was using. This is what my file looks like now. It's the full file, so can you see anything wrong here: http://pastie.org/10280430?

Comment: I will check again to make sure the strings match

Comment: That file looks fine to me.

Comment: darn, yeah I am not seeing a problem either. I just went through my files and verified they are injecting correctly. Would seeing the minified file help at all?

Comment: Yeah that might help... Although it's probably going to be hard to read if it's all on one line. If you know how to turn off the removal of white space that might be nice.

Comment: try this link: http://pastebin.com/6TvftW0u, my code starts at line 569, most of the stuff before is TweenLite and a different plugin. I ran the code through www.unminify.com

Comment: if you ctrl+f 'VforumJS' it should point you to all my controllers/models/services etc

Comment: If you run that minified file (with all the white space still in it) do you get a error on a line number at least? I'm looking through it but I'm not seeing anything obvious jump out at me.

Comment: Correct, it works when it is not minified. I get the same error if use what was pasted on pastebin (with the whitespace still there) and no line number, It is pointing to the angular.min.js file

Answer (score 0):

Your VforumJsConfig line is the issue

```
var VforumJsConfig = function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, localStorageServiceProvider)
```

The function parameters get minified, and angular doesn't know where to inject them from.  You need to supply them as strings ( just like your other functions ), as strings won't be altered during minification.

From the docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification

So you will need to add after the definition of VforumJsConfig:

```
VforumJsConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'localStorageServiceProvider']
```

Comment: Won't they way he's doing it now work? (See his edited post)

Comment: I believe I am doing this already: `.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'localStorageServiceProvider', VforumJsConfig])
`

Comment: You're right, I was looking at it wrong.  From the code you've provided, it does look correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use the array syntax for VforumJsConfig so that the dependencies are defined explicitly rather than implied by the parameter names which will be minified.  Instead of:

```
var VforumJsConfig = function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, 

localStorageServiceProvider)
{
  localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('vforumdesktop');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    ...
  })
  .otherwise({
    ...
  });
};
```

Try:

```
var VforumJsConfig = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, localStorageServiceProvider)
{
  localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('vforumdesktop');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    ...
  })
  .otherwise({
    ...
  });
}];
```